Ошибка CORS политики при запросе скрипта JS API Яндекс.Карт
согласно документации подключаю скрипт карт на сайт
<!-- Вместо YOUR_API_KEY подставить значение настоящего ключа -->
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/v3/?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY&lang=ru_RU"></script>

в консоли в инструментах разработчика вижу, что запрос выполнен успешно, но он не доступен из-за CORS политики

пишет, что в ответе API нет заголовка 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
как это починить? доменное имя сайта добавлено в http_referer в кабинете разработчика

А cкрипт вы подключаете в шапке страницы или через вызов из вашего скрипта index.js?
